# Web sockets in Next.JS 13

Tags: next.js, websocket, socket.io, next.js13

Just a quick question,
Using the current Next 13.2+ route handler. How do we build a web socket

I tried using it in the GET handler but it didn’t work. And I’ve tried searching through the docs for a solution but there was none